# Is there a voice over api which get delay focus status?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm a new in iOS. I making the app which include voice over functions. My app consisted of **collection view** from table view. The app had check box(?? no button just image) and that show checked/unchecked status. 

When I checked the check box and then voice over reading this. -> [self.checkBoxImageView setAccessibilityHint:@"~~~~"];

Correct operation(voice over reading) when I tried first time but, **after second time the voice over reading reversed**.

 How can I modified to fix my code which I want operation.

 Attach my code below.

=========================first function=========================

```
- (void)setChecked:(BOOL)checked {
NSLog(@"%s, checked = %d", __func__, _checked);
NSLog(@"[D] checked : %d", checked);
// Save property value
_checked  = checked;

// Update checkbox image
NSString * filename;

if(checked)
{
    filename = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"check_on" ofType:@"png"];
    [self.checkBoxImageView setAccessibilityHint:@"Checked"];

}
else
{
    filename = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"check_off" ofType:@"png"];
    [self.checkBoxImageView setAccessibilityHint:@"Unchecked"];
}

[self.checkBoxImageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filename]];

NSLog(@"[D] self.checkBoxImageView setImage:[UIImage");
self.checkBoxImageView.frame = CGRectMake(12, 12, 50/2, 50/2);
NSLog(@"[D] self.checkBoxImageView.frame = CGRectMake");
}
```

=========================another function=========================

```
- (void) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __func__);
    NSLog(@"%@", indexPath.description);

    //[collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    //// Get selected cell
    //MYCell* cell = (MYCell*) [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cv deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    // Get selected cell
    MYCell* cell = (MYCell*) [cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

//    if (cell.checked == NO)
//        cell.checked = YES;
//    else if (cell.checked == YES)
//        cell.checked = NO;

    // Check if set contains selected cell indexPath
    if([self.checkedIndexPaths member:indexPath])
    {
        // User tapped on checked cell
        // Remove selected indexPath from set
        [self.checkedIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];

        // Uncheck checkbox on cell
        cell.checked = NO;
    }
    else // User tapped on unchecked cell
    {
        // Add selected indexPath to set
        [self.checkedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];

        // Check checkbox on cell
        cell.checked = YES;
    }


}
```

Comment: If you should focused not check box and retry focused check box and then correct operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessibility hints are intended to be extra information about what an element does. As such the voice over system assumes that the content will mostly remain static (unless the layout of the page changes). Also note that many users have them turned off even when voice over mode is on.

The property that you should be setting in this case is `accessibilityValue` ([Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615117-accessibilityvalue)). This is used for dynamic content in an element, such as the text in a UITextField.

Comment: Thank you so much~!!! I visited the apple doc site and downloaded sample code. I run this code that is what I want. But...I'm a new in iOS.......so It's me hard to apply the my code...I will try more and more! Thanks a lot!! Have a nice day~